# How do I start an Activity from a Service?

Tags: android, service, permissions, android-activity

So I've been searching around for a week or so, and it appears to be quite possible to start an `Activity` from a `Service`, the general order of things going like this:

```
    Intent myIntent = new Intent();
    myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    myIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("[package]", "[class]"));
    getApplication().startActivity(myIntent);
```

When trying this from a WallpaperService, I'm getting what appears to be a wallpaper-specific error `requires android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER`. Stack trace shows the startActivity as the culprit.

I have no idea how to give it this permission; I have tried putting `android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER"` on every tag in the manifest that'll take it, as well as `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" />`

Notably, the debug view does have the warning:

> WARN/PackageManager(59): Not granting permission
>   android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER to package (protectionLevel=3
>   flags=0xbe46)

General question being asked is in the title.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You want to put android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER" inside only the service tag and nowhere else.